# Java circular reference error

Tags: java

I need some help .

i have class A:

```
 class A {
List<B> listB;

A() {
    listB = new ArrayList<B>();
    listB.add(new B("1"));
    listB.add(new B("2"));
    listB.add(new B("3"));
    listB.add(new B("4"));
}

public void clean() {
    for (B b : listB) {
        b.clean();
    }
    this.listB = null;
}
```

}

and class B:

```
class B {
String id = "";
A a = new A();

B(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void clean() {
    a = null;
}
```

}

and main :

```
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    a.clean();
}
```

}

i just want to set null for A and B but i got this Error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError"

Can someone explain this for me . Thanks.

Comment: whilst this doesn´t compile because `A#A` constructor isn´t a valid syntax, Imagine what happens when you create an instance of `A` in the main. What does it do? It creates a `List` of `B`, each generating a new `A`. Do you remember what happend when creating an instance of `A` in your `main`? guess what will happen next after the new `A` instance was created in the first instance of `B` in the `List` of your first `A`. It will continuesly create a `List` of `B`, intializes a new `B`, where it generates a new `A`, which will create a `List` of `B`, which will initialize a new `A` and so on.

Comment: Thanks Kenvin . i got your ideas

Comment: You can fix this error by replacing A a = new A(); with static A a = new A();